# Turning a character to face another direction right and left movement not working

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple text based game where the user is put in a cave and based on what room he enters and what direction he's facing he would get a description of what he senses. I have gotten it to work with his starting position and moving him forward but for some reason he won't turn.

```
Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
            
Point dirE = new Point(1, 0); //EAST
Point dirS = new Point(0, 1); //South
Point dirN = new Point(-1, 0); //North
Point dirW = new Point(0, -1); //WEST

Point playerDir = dirE;
Boolean alive = true;

// Point playerDir = dirE;
// Boolean alive = true;
Point nextRoom = pos.add(playerDir);
while (alive == true)
{
    String cmd = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
          
    //Directions
    if (playerDir == dirE && cmd == "R")
    {
        playerDir = dirS;
    }
    if (cmd == "F")
    {
        if (playerDir == dirW && pos.x > 0)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
        if (playerDir == dirE && pos.x < 3)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
        if (playerDir == dirS && pos.y < 3)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
        if (playerDir == dirN && pos.y > 0)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
                    
        try
        {
            nextRoom = pos.add(playerDir);
            if (board[nextRoom.x, nextRoom.y] == "L")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Feel Heat");
            }
            else if (board[nextRoom.x, nextRoom.y] == "N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You feel nothing");
            }
            else if (board[nextRoom.x, nextRoom.y] == "G")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You see a small glow");
            }
            else if (board[nextRoom.x, nextRoom.y] == "S")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You smell rust");
            }
       }
       catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("You can not move forward there a wall in front of you");
    }
}
```

I have tried to check South and thought I possibley wrote the cords wrong and swapped it to 0,-1 which did nothing and I also attempted to change int the if statement from
`playerDir = dirS;` to `playerDir = pos.add(dirS)` and still nothing
I suspect that my logic is wrong despite being told that this should work by someone more knowledgeable.
Edit~
It should be noted that I am currently testing moving east and then turning to move south.

My point class if that helps understand my current code

```
class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int tx, int ty)
    {
        x = tx;
        y = ty;
    }

    public Point add(Point other)
    {
        int newX = this.x + other.x;
        int newY = this.y + other.y;
        return new Point(newX, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you might want to check your indentation because it is quite confusing.

Comment: Also, are you sure this is the right code? Because this is not valid. You are declaring `playerDir` and `alive` twice

Comment: Also, it is not whats causing the problem in your code, but usually in c# we prefer to use `bool` instead of `Boolean`.

Comment: I 'm trying to see where I have playerDir and alive twice. Also thanks for the tip I've been coding in java and this is my first time with c#

Comment: In that case, you might also want to consider using properties instead of public fields. Or if `Point` shall be immutable, make it a record (or struct if older version).

Comment: Anyways, coming from Java, you should be familiar with OOP. Maybe it gets clearer if you abstract a little, here? Obviously, you'll want to have more rooms later, ...

Comment: I've submitted an edit to tidy up the indentation, and I've taken the liberty of commenting out the lines which are declaring `playerDir` and `alive` a second time. It won't be visible until someone has peer reviewed and approved it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem here...

```
// This line sets the next room that the player will move to
Point nextRoom = pos.add(playerDir);

while (alive == true)
{
    String cmd = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
          
    // This sets the direction that the player will move in
    if (playerDir == dirE && cmd == "R")
    {
        playerDir = dirS;
    }

    // This supposedly sets the player's next room, but that was set before we decided what direction he was facing
    if (cmd == "F")
    {
        if (playerDir == dirW && pos.x > 0)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
        // remaining code omitted for brevity
```

Try changing the order of execution, so that the player turns before working out which room to move to, e.g.

```
while (alive == true)
{
    String cmd = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
          
    // This sets the direction that the player will move in
    if (playerDir == dirE && cmd == "R")
    {
        playerDir = dirS;
    }

    // This line sets the next room that the player will move to
    Point nextRoom = pos.add(playerDir);

    // This should move the player to the correct room
    if (cmd == "F")
    {
        if (playerDir == dirW && pos.x > 0)
        {
            pos = nextRoom;
        }
        // remaining code omitted for brevity
```

Comment: I just saw this post and you confirmed it. I attempted to switch them while I was messing with the code and it appeared to have work so I kept it that way. Your statement solidifies that.

Comment: If you found this helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers